# single quote escape inside double quotes using sequel fetch function in ruby

Tags: ruby, sequel

using raw SQL when I use the IN statement inside a query using sequel's fetch function, I can't escape a single quote by writing where stuff IN ...

```
@values='stuff1\'','stuff2\''

db.fetch("query...where IN (?)", "#{@values}")
```

outputs `query...where stuff IN ('stuff1'',''stuff2')` instead of `('stuff1','stuff2')`

Quite frustrating that I'd probably have to write a Sequel equivalent for the raw query  or use a different ORM just because of this escape issue. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the [Sequel documentation](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/security_rdoc.html) correctly, using `String#lit` or `Sequel.lit` should turn a Ruby string into a literal string and bypass the automatic escaping mechanism; therefore, this should work (untested):

```
@values='stuff1\'','stuff2\''.lit

db.fetch("query...where IN (?)", "#{@values}")
```

The usual caveats when working with raw SQL strings (SQL injection attacks, inefficient SQL due to forced re-parsing of statements etc.) apply :-)

Answer (score 3):

You should probably do something like:

```
@values = ['stuff1', 'stuff2']
db.fetch("query...where IN ?", @values)
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken my testing indicates that this will not work.  The where clause generated will be:
`WHERE column in (N'stuff1' = N'stuff2')`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
values = Sequel.lit("'stuff1', 'stuff2'")
db.fetch("SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE COL1 IN ?", values)
```

See also: [How to pass a list to an IN clause via a placeholder with Ruby Sequel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71792230/how-to-pass-a-list-to-an-in-clause-via-a-placeholder-with-ruby-sequel)