# How to pass a list to an IN clause via a placeholder with Ruby Sequel

Tags: ruby, sequel

I am trying to pass a quoted list to a placeholder in an `IN` clause with Ruby Sequel.

Specifically:

```
query = "
SELECT *
FROM PRICE
WHERE REGION IN (?)"
```

Then I use Ruby Sequel: `dataset = dbr[query, param_values]; dataset.sql`.
If I pass `param_values` as a string like this: `param_values = "'NSW1', 'VIC1'"`, the where clause becomes:
`WHERE REGION IN ((N'''NSW1'', ''VIC1'''))` which doesn't work - presumably too many quotes.  If I try passing the parameter as an array of quoted strings like this: `param_values = %w[NSW1 VIC1]`
the where clause becomes: `WHERE REGION IN ((N'NSW1' = N'VIC1'))` which won't work.

Is there something that will work?

Comment: Have also tried removing the WHERE from the custom SQL and using a dataset `.where`.  However, that doesn't change the query and the documentation confirms that I might expect that.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [Sequel's query builder language](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel) instead of writing SQL manually which would look like this if you used default naming conventions:

```
DB[:prices]
  .select(:date, :price, :region_id)
  .where(region_id: %w[NSW1 VIC1])
```

Comment: Yes - thanks @spickermann.  I do have a case for using custom SQL, so I would prefer to run native SQL.

Comment: While there are occasions to use custom SQL, they will be much less than you'd expect, and won't take advantage of the object structures that are of such benefit to ruby. If you really need to do this, you'll need a `?` for each element in the array, but since it's a string, you could just use `str += '(' + Array.new(array.count, '?').join(',') + ')'` or similar

Comment: I have the SQL in an external configuration file - so hacking the where clause like that is messy.   But thanks for that suggestion @Jad. I might end up simply replacing the IN with an = and call the query for each element of the array and concatenate the results..

Comment: if the SQL is in an external configuration file, can you configure it to be in sections [select, joins, where], rather than a "blob", so that you can splice in @spickermann's suggestion?

Comment: Thanks - `Sequel.lit` solved the problem.   See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23538566/single-quote-escape-inside-double-quotes-using-sequel-fetch-function-in-ruby/71803944#71803944

Answer (score 1):

```
query = "
SELECT *
FROM PRICE
WHERE REGION IN ?"
regions = Sequel.lit("'NSW1', 'VIC1'")
sql = db.fetch(query, regions).sql
puts "sql: #{sql}"
```

Gives:

```
sql: SELECT *
FROM PRICE
WHERE REGION IN ('NSW1', 'VIC1')
```

which is what we want.

Comment: Actually - this answer isn't all that good.  The array has to be quoted as given literally above.